# WPF datagrid dynamic columns disappear

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am building a simple 2 tab C# WPF application. On first tab I have Datagrid and Checkbox. Datagrids itemsource is bound to ViewModel ObservableCollection. On checkbox check I am adding to datagrid dynamically one column. Till now everything works fine, however when I switch between two tabs the dynamically created column disappearing while the checkbox still remains checked. Any idea where to look? thx

Comment: Please post code . . .

Comment: Screen capture would be really helpful as well

Answer (score 0):

Does your second tab have a datagrid as a component? It might just well be that you have a tab that is binding to an unknown data source. However without code, it's very hard to tell.